# How to mask each region in image within boundary

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I would like to compute some factor inside the a boundary. I have the coordinates of this boundary. I must use a rectangle which each iteration is moving though the image. However, I cannot apply boundary for this rectangle.
how to set the inside the of the boundary to 1 and 0 for the rest for each rectangle in MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

Turn your coordinates into integers. Then, function [poly2mask](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/poly2mask.html) can convert your boundary to a binary mask, with this syntax:

```
BW = poly2mask(x, y, m, n)
```

where x and y are vectors with a list of coordinates of boundary points; m and n are the width and height for the new binary image `BW`. Example (adapted from link above):

```
x = [63 186 190 54 63];
y = [60 60 204 209 60];
bw = poly2mask(x,y,256,256);
imshow(bw)
```

[image: Link to resulting figure]

Then, for a rectangle in coordinates (i,j), with width w and height h, you would get the information you want as

```
i = 128; j = 128;
w = 100; h = 100;

aux = bw(i:i + h - 1, j:j + w - 1);

figure, imshow(aux)
```

Comment: Thanks for your wised answer. However, I need something more. Suppose that I have the overall boundary of a city based on longitudes (X) and latitudes (Y). Now I download an rectangular image which I should mask it based on the overall boundary. This rectangular image can be anywhere of the city. I would like to remind  that there are two separate image  in two different zoom levels.

Comment: @MohammadAliNematollahi None of this is in your original question. Changing the requirements after someone has been kind enough to provide an answer is very poor manners.

Comment: Since which version of Matlab is poly2mask available?